# How can I fix tqdm Iprogress import problem?

Tags: tqdm

I am execucting   in python38: tqdm(train_ImageDataloader_ResNet):
There is a problem importing the component that disiplays the progess bar.

File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tqdm\notebook.py", line 242, in **init**
self.container = self.status_printer(self.fp, total, self.desc, self.ncols)
File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tqdm\notebook.py", line 118, in status_printer
raise ImportError(WARN_NOIPYW)
ImportError: IProgress not found. Please update jupyter and ipywidgets. See
https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html

I have installed ipywidgets and iprogress, I am not using Jupyter notebook.
what can I do?